# Expand UITableViewCell with multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to expand my UITableViewCells with a UITableView that has multiple sections. The way I'm doing it is as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    habitTableView.beginUpdates()
    habitTableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (selectedRowIndex != nil && indexPath == selectedRowIndex!){

        return 147
    }
    return 90
}
```

However there are some strange behaviors, for example, if one cell expands it sort of "eats up" the next section header underneath it so the section header disappears. I am just wondering - is there any nuances with a UITableView that has multiple sections?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can do one thing is to have two protocol type of `UITableViewCell`. One is for normal and another one is for expanded. Once you type on a cell, you just need to update the delegate to use expanded one instead normal one. When updating, you only need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to prevent reload everything.

You only need to create one more cell prototype and have a boolean value for indicating the state. Then, add your logic to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.